# Should my custom User model be an abstract class?

Tags: python, django

I created a project with a custom User model, and profiles linked to my user, this way:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ...

class BizProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   # ....

class CliProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   # ....
```

I just realised that functionally, I create BizProfile or CliProfile, but it makes no sens to create a User only in my project.

In that case, should I make my User class abstract? What are the pro's and con's of doing this? Currently, it's not abstract but works well.

Thanks.

Comment: As @knbk answered, use a base custom user or django user (if you don't need to alter the main fields used for auth etc) then add the profile as a One to One field (as you have done here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible.

An abstract model is a model that doesn't exist in the database. For a foreign key to work, both models have to exist in the database. The data in the `User` model also needs to be saved to the database anyway.

It's also not possible to somehow have two separate user models (e.g. `BizUser` and `CliUser`), as all code in Django and other third-party apps expects that there is a single user model and won't work with multiple models.